# How to convert .plt file to csv file and also attributes are missing?

Tags: r

First I converted the .plt file to a .txt file then I imported in R.

But when I try to read the text file, I get an error:

```
`20081023025304` <- read.table("C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/Dataset/final_Geolife Trajectories 1.3/Geolife Trajectories 1.3/Data/000/Trajectory/20081023025304.plt", header=TRUE, quote="\"")
Error in read.table("C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/Dataset/final_Geolife Trajectories 1.3/Geolife Trajectories 1.3/Data/000/Trajectory/20081023025304.plt", : 
  more columns than column names

View(`20081023025304`)
Error in View : object '20081023025304' not found
```

I am having 7 attributes in my datasets but I am getting 5 attributes and also  error. I want to get full attributes then only I can analyze my process.

```
Geolife trajectory
WGS 84
Altitude is in Feet
Reserved 3
0,2,255,My Track,0,0,2,8421376
0

39.984702,116.318417,0,492,39744.1201851852,2008-10-23,02:53:04
39.984683,116.31845,0,492,39744.1202546296,2008-10-23,02:53:10
39.984686,116.318417,0,492,39744.1203125,2008-10-23,02:53:15
39.984688,116.318385,0,492,39744.1203703704,2008-10-23,02:53:20
39.984655,116.318263,0,492,39744.1204282407,2008-10-23,02:53:25
39.984611,116.318026,0,493,39744.1204861111,2008-10-23,02:53:30
39.984608,116.317761,0,493,39744.1205439815,2008-10-23,02:53:35
39.984563,116.317517,0,496,39744.1206018519,2008-10-23,02:53:40
39.984539,116.317294,0,500,39744.1206597222,2008-10-23,02:53:45
39.984606,116.317065,0,505,39744.1207175926,2008-10-23,02:53:50
39.984568,116.316911,0,510,39744.120775463,2008-10-23,02:53:55
39.984586,116.316716,0,515,39744.1208333333,2008-10-23,02:54:00
```

Comment: Please copy and paste in your question the command you used as well as the error message

Comment: When you read the file, you must skip 7 lines. In `read.table()`, use argument `skip = 7`.

Comment: > `20081023025304` <- read.table("C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/Dataset/final_Geolife Trajectories 1.3/Geolife Trajectories 1.3/Data/000/Trajectory/20081023025304.plt", header=TRUE, quote="\"")
>Error in read.table("C:/Users/ADMIN/Desktop/Dataset/final_Geolife Trajectories 1.3/Geolife Trajectories 1.3/Data/000/Trajectory/20081023025304.plt",  : 
  more columns than column names
>   View(`20081023025304`)
Error in View : object '20081023025304' not found

Comment: You need arguments `skip = 7` and `sep = ","` in `read.table()`. And **most importatnly**, don't use such syntax `20081023025304` <- . It makes things more complicated to access this object.

Comment: may i know how to skip =7 ?

Comment: I told you. Use argument `skip` in `read.table()`. Please read `?read.table`.

Comment: thank so much sir.. i got all 7 variables now

Answer (score 3):

You need to skip 7 lines before reading your data. Also, the separator is `,`. So you need something like

```
read.table("file.plt", header = TRUE, quote = "\"", skip = 7, sep = ",")
```